# How to acces to this variable in java?

Tags: java

I'm beginner in Java, I'm coming from C#. Look at this code:

```
public class Ampel {
    public Ampel(boolean r, boolean y, boolean g) {
        boolean red = r,
                yellow = y,
                green = g;
    }
    public void GetStand() {
        System.out.println(red);
        System.out.println(yellow);
        System.out.println(green);
    }
}
```

I can't acces to "red" or "yellow" and "green" in `GetStand()`. What should I do?

Comment: declare red, yellow, blue outside the constructor so they're members of the class.

Comment: Um, I'm guessing that C# has variable scoping.

Comment: @Brian, yes, it's block scoped.

Comment: @MikeSamuel My point was that it would be exactly the same issue in c#.

Comment: In Java, all methods begin with a lower-case letter as opposed to C#'s syntax.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: It's not a matter of syntax - it's a matter of convention.

Comment: @Jon I know, that is why I left a comment, not an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: My point is that your comment is incorrect: it implies that this is a *rule* in Java, and that it's part of *syntax*.

Comment: Ok, to answer OP, you are creating local variables within the scope of the constructor and not the class. When you try to reference said variables inside of another method, they cannot be seen as they can only be visible to the constructor. To resolve this, the variables should be declared outside of methods, but inside the class.

Answer (score 3):

You're currently declaring *local* variables in the constructor. You need to declare *instance* variables. For example:

```
public class Ampel {
    private final boolean red;
    private final boolean yellow;
    private final boolean green;

    public Ampel(boolean r, boolean y, boolean g) {
        red = r;
        yellow = y;
        green = g;
    }

    // Name changed to follow Java casing conventions, but it's still odd to have
    // a "get" method which doesn't return anything...
    public void getStand() {
        System.out.println(red);
        System.out.println(yellow);
        System.out.println(green);
    }
}
```

Note that the equivalent C# code would work exactly the same way. This *isn't* a difference between Java and C#.

Comment: Hi Jon, I can't test this at the moment. But if this were C# should not red, yellow and green be declared as `readonly` instead of `final` in C#? Please let me know if I am mistaken.

Comment: @robbmj: Yes, but I'm not showing C# - I'm showing Java, because that's what the OP's writing in. The *equivalent* C# code would use `readonly` rather than `final`.

Answer (score 0):

Define the booleans as class attributes rather than variables in constructor scope.

Answer (score 0):

Define red, yellow and green as instance variables.

```
public class Ampel {
    private boolean red, yellow, green;
    public Ampel(boolean r, boolean y, boolean g) {
        red = r;
        yellow = y;
        green = g;
   }

   public void getStand() { // java convention is to camelCase method names
       System.out.println(red);
       System.out.println(yellow);
       System.out.println(green);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, missed the comas, that should have been turned into semi colons.